# Using keyword in a C++ interface declaration

Tags: c++, delphi, interface

I'm porting Direct2D *d2d1_1.h* header file to Delphi and I'm stuck with a declaration. I don't understand clearly (**Line 1522** in *d2d_1.h*):

```
interface DX_DECLARE_INTERFACE("e8f7fe7a-191c-466d-ad95-975678bda998") ID2D1DeviceContext  : public ID2D1RenderTarget
{
    STDMETHOD(CreateBitmap)(
        D2D1_SIZE_U size,
        _In_opt_ CONST void *sourceData,
        UINT32 pitch,
        _In_ CONST D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 *bitmapProperties,
        _COM_Outptr_ ID2D1Bitmap1 **bitmap
        ) PURE;    

    using ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap;       //<<<<<====== This line

    // More code deleted for simplicity
}; // ID2D1DeviceContext
```

In Delphi there is no such concept as "*using*" keyword in interface declaration.

**My question is:** Should I simply ignore this line because C++ compiler does some magic or should I reproduce `ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap` declaration?

IMO an interface is actually an array of pointer to all methods. So I guess I have to reproduce the declaration from the inherited interface so that his slot is occupied.

Comment: This is C++ and not C, and as such I have corrected the tags. You can find out what using means by websearch. It's important to note that the language is C++ for that.

Comment: Thanks @David Heffernan, but the question is not about what it does in C++. I read that in the docs. The question is how to translate to Delphi which lacks the concept of using keyword. I think there is two solutions - as I already mentionned - either ignore that line or reproduce the referenced declaration.

Comment: The question is about what the C++ code means. When you understand that you know how to translate to Delphi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When porting from C++ to Delphi, the methods declared with "using" keyword must simply be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Should I simply ignore this line because C compiler does some magic or should I reproduce ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap declaration?

`using` declaration is basically introducing a type defined elsewhere into the current scope. It has the effect of allowing to write `CreateBitmap` instead of `ID2D1RenderTarget::CreateBitmap`.

Comment: OK, this is what I understood and did not answer to my question. I reformulate: is the using declaration add an entry in the array of pointers which in the binary representation of an interface? And why would someone bring a declaration from the inherited interface? Are they not automatically visible? Is this to overload the existing declaration instead of override it?